# Windows 10 is Super Super Slow

Tags: windows-10-upgrade, windows-10

I upgraded from windows 8.1 to windows 10. I updated all of my drivers and windows itself. But still is super slow and it shows that It only uses 1% CPU and 10% ram. However, even the a right click takes around 1 min. Also, if I want to open file explorer takes around 4 min.

My PC: Core i7 
        / 8 G ram
        / Nvidia GT 740 M

Comment: What is your disk usage ? If it's high try using the performance monitor to check what's using it so much.

Comment: Problems like this are normally in my experience connected to a HDD problem.

Comment: @Ramhound I checked my disk usage, it's 5%.

Comment: I'd rule out hardware first. Try a livedisc (ubuntu or other linux are fine for this) and use the hardware check utilities to ensure the HDD is in working order.